# How can we explicitly call garbage collector in ARC? Also is there a way we can decide when to release memory in ARC?

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am an iPhone Developer. I am using ARC in my application. I am allocating objects and once its use is over I assign "nil" to it. Is there anything else I need to do in order to get the memory released?

Also is there a way, we can explicitly call garbage collector in ARC? Also is there a way we can decide when to release memory in ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no garbage collection with ARC, so there is nothing to call.  If you control the scope and ownership of your objects, ARC will look after the memory use for you.

Apart from assigning 'nil' to a reference or letting the reference go out of scope, the only other consideration is whether you have some extra reference to the object (such as putting it into a NSArray) that has it's own need to retain the object.

Comment: I'm not saying it is your fault but.. "ARC is not a Garbage Collector", "Arc will take care of your garbage", "There is no garbage collection with ARC" - I hope someone has a better way to teach beginners this stuff.

Comment: @hooleyhoop - I don't get what you're trying to say.  With the appropriate definitions and conditions, two of those are true statements.  And the only thing wrong with "Arc will take care of your garbage" is that ARC is more about preventing it than taking care of it.

Comment: Sorry for trolling. I find it confusing but can do no better myself (i'm unsatisfied that it is so difficult to explain, not that i think you did a bad job).

Comment: While everything in this answer is correct, @justin's is more complete.  There are cases where `@autoreleasepool` blocks are necessary in order to prevent defunct objects from accumulating in memory (ARC will release them eventually, but possibly not until the thread itself terminates).  Not everything will be released as soon as it leaves scope, unless your scope also happens to include an `@autoreleasepool` block.

Answer (score 9):

ARC is not a Garbage Collector -- think of it as manual reference count management, where the compiler adds reference count operations on your behalf.

One good thing you can do is to create an autorelease pool. Because the compiler adds retain, release, and autorelease messages -- your objects end up in autorelease pools. Consider:

```
@autoreleasepool {
  ..create several temporary objects...
} // << now the autorelease pool is popped, and delayed release messages are sent
```

Creating autorelease pools is very cheap, and can really keep your memory consumption down and ensure your objects' resources are returned promptly.